# I got a Force close with my If statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

```
    Button s2;
AutoCompleteTextView tran;
//Spinner lang;
EditText trans;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.translate);     



    s2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tran= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    trans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    s2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View dap) {
            String input;
            String output= null;
            input = tran.getText().toString();


        if ("Love".equals(input)){

        trans.setText("Italian: Amore"+"\n Spanish:  Amor"+"\n Japanese: ai / koi"+"\n Mandarin:  ai");

        } 


        else
        {trans.setText(null);}
```

I have read a lot about if statement, and I use this `if ("Love".equals(input))` code. Every time I click the button (s2) I got force close. Is there anything wrong with my if statement?.

these are the lines that appears in my logcat.

```
03-08 05:50:40.952: D/Vold(29): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
03-08 05:50:40.992: W/Vold(29): No UMS switch available
03-08 05:50:41.072: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
03-08 05:50:41.072: D/qemud(38): created client 0xe078 listening on fd 8
03-08 05:50:41.092: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 8
03-08 05:50:41.222: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
03-08 05:50:41.222: D/qemud(38): created client 0xf028 listening on fd 8
03-08 05:50:41.232: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'gsm'
03-08 05:50:41.232: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 1
03-08 05:50:41.242: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 1
03-08 05:50:41.443: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
03-08 05:50:41.443: D/qemud(38): created client 0x10fd8 listening on fd 11
03-08 05:50:41.472: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'boot-properties'
03-08 05:50:41.472: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 2
03-08 05:50:41.482: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 2
03-08 05:50:41.482: I/qemu-props(54): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
03-08 05:50:41.492: I/qemu-props(54): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m
03-08 05:50:41.522: I/qemu-props(54): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240
03-08 05:50:41.542: I/qemu-props(54): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
03-08 05:50:41.562: I/qemu-props(54): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=back
03-08 05:50:41.602: I/qemu-props(54): received: 
03-08 05:50:41.602: I/qemu-props(54): invalid format, ignored.
03-08 05:50:44.592: D/AndroidRuntime(33): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-08 05:50:44.612: D/AndroidRuntime(33): CheckJNI is ON
03-08 05:50:46.853: I/(34): ServiceManager: 0xacd0
03-08 05:50:46.853: D/AudioHardwareInterface(34): setMode(NORMAL)
03-08 05:50:46.913: I/CameraService(34): CameraService started: pid=34
03-08 05:50:46.992: I/AudioFlinger(34): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb3b8 ready to run
03-08 05:50:47.254: D/AndroidRuntime(33): --- registering native functions ---
03-08 05:50:49.533: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(33): Profiler is disabled.
03-08 05:50:49.783: I/Zygote(33): Preloading classes...
03-08 05:50:49.793: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
03-08 05:50:49.843: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 821 objects / 47496 bytes in 41ms

03-08 05:51:40.743: E/BatteryService(68): usbOnlinePath not found
03-08 05:51:40.743: E/BatteryService(68): batteryVoltagePath not found
03-08 05:51:40.753: E/BatteryService(68): batteryTemperaturePath not found
03-08 05:51:40.823: I/sysproc(68): Entered system_init()
03-08 05:51:40.823: I/sysproc(68): ServiceManager: 0x11d650
03-08 05:51:40.856: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): SurfaceFlinger is starting
03-08 05:51:40.863: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
03-08 05:51:40.903: E/SurfaceFlinger(68): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
03-08 05:51:41.003: I/gralloc(68): using (fd=25)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `input = tran.getText().toString()` should be `trans`, not `tran`, , and there is an extra quote at the first `'trans`. But I'm guessing those are somehow copy/paste errors. If they are not, I strongly suspect that is your problem.

Comment: The if statement looks OK. What about the prvious line, is `tran` initialized (not null)?

Comment: tran= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

this is my initialization, my tran is the input word. the trans is the translated word to be displayed in the editText. the (') is mistakenly typed here at my post. As what looks, it should be okay but it closes all the time. Thank You.

Comment: Button s2;

 AutoCompleteTextView tran;


 EditText trans;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.translate);  
  
 
  
  s2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

  tran= (AutoCompleteTextView) 
findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

  trans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);




. This is my initialization.

Comment: Hard to tell - the logcat should give a hint on whats going on. Try to get it and append the relevant lines to your question (edit the question, not as a comment, please).

Comment: if("test".equals(null)) always returns false. so no problem with if condition

Answer (score 2):

change your else with **trans.setText("")** instead of trans.setText(null);